# Webpack not inject javascript to cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Hi I have a MVC 5 project with lots of frontend code in javascript. So I decided to modularize those javascript ==>  inject them to cshtml templates ==> render partial them in my View
My config:

```
webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
entry: {
    layout: './Public/js/Layout.js', 
    index: './ViewModules/Home/Index.js',
    noisoisieuam: './ViewModules/KetQua/NoiSoiSieuAm.js'
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Public/Output'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.[contenthash].js',
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        templateContent: '',
        filename: '../../../ViewModules/Shared/_Layout.temp.cshtml',
        chunks: [ 'layout']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true, 
        templateContent: '',
        filename: '../../../ViewModules/Home/Index.temp.cshtml',
        chunks: ['index']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true, 
        templateContent: '',
        filename: '../../../ViewModules/KetQua/NoiSoiSieuAm.temp.cshtml',
        chunks: ['noisoisieuam']
    })
],
// IMPORTANT NOTE: If you are using Webpack 2 or above, replace "loaders" with "rules"
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                        }
                }
            ],
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            type: 'javascript/auto',
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: "[path][name].[ext]"
                    }
                }
            ],                
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The `*.temp.cshtml` files are empty cshtml files only for javascript injection.
Code in my respective `*.cshtml` (my View):

```
    ...
@Html.Partial("~/ViewModules/<path-to-template>/*.temp.cshtml")
...
```

The problem is only the first 2 temp.cshtml are injected by webpack (the `_Layout` and my home page).

`npm run build` or build in Visual Studio dont give any error. Those javascript bundles all created. The `'noisoisieuam'` chunk is not injected to my temp.cshtml

How can I fix this? Thank you very much